# How to create a Database in Office 365 online

Tags: database, sqlite, office365

The company where I work implemented Office 365 online last year, and I can use apps via web, such as Outlook, Word, Excel, OneDrive, SharePoint, etc. It's cool, since we can access the information from everywhere through every device.

My department manages a database where we store data of customers, products and orders in three interlinked tables, created with SQLite. We keep it up-to-date in a folder of an old Windows server, where three people have permissions to write, and ten people to read, allowing them to generate reports.

It would be great if Office 365 could allow to create an online database to do this: build interlinked tables, with read/write permissions, and an API to generate reports from local apps.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: You can look into MS Access.

Comment: Is "MS Access" available in "Office 365 online"? At least, not in the "Office 365 online" of my company. It's included in the desktop apps of the "Office 365". But, how can I access an Access file remotely through the servers of Microsoft, granting permissions, with a web interface, etc.? This is possible with Excel or Power Point, but not sure with MS Access.